# pyautogui and pywinauto combine to click application in background

Tags: python, pyautogui, pywinauto

**what i am trying to do:**
i trying to use the code below to locate and give me a X and Y position of the image

```
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('accept.png')
```

after locating the image, i am trying to use pywinauto* to click on the image location in the background.

```
form.click(button='left', pressed='', coords=(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('accept.png')), double=False, absolute=False)
```

**problem:**
nothing seems to happen.. i dont understand why. i checked on the pywinauto* and pyautogui "cheat sheets" it seems okay
someone please enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

The correct spelling is "pywinauto". Method `.click_input(...)` with the same params is what you need as it moves the cursor and performs realistic click.

Method `.click(...)` silently sends window messages like `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` which may not work for some UI elements if they don't handle it.